# Grid in GraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I want to implement grid in my graphicsView such that it fits to the graphicsView automatically and when I zoom in the graphicsView only the block size of grid should increase but not the line width of the grid. I tried the following but nothing happened.

```
void CadGraphicsScene::grid(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{
    QPen pen;
    painter->setPen(pen);

    qreal left = int(rect.left()) - (int(rect.left()) % gridSize);
    qreal top = int(rect.top()) - (int(rect.top()) % gridSize);
    QVector<QPointF> points;
    for (qreal x = left; x < rect.right(); x += gridSize){
        for (qreal y = top; y < rect.bottom(); y += gridSize){
            points.append(QPointF(x,y));
        }
    }
    painter->drawPoints(points.data(), points.size());
}
```

Please help me out to make a grid.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what the problem ist? "nothing happens" is a bit broad. Is your method called but nothing at all painted?

Comment: Yes, my slot is called but nothing is painted when I click on menu Item. What I have done is on clicking of menu Item this slot is called. But on doing so nothing get painted.

Comment: Where is the painter coming from, which is being passed to the grid function?

Comment: @Merlin069 Painter is an object to QPainter class which is declared while declaration of fuction.

Comment: I know what a QPainter is, but where is the object instantiated in your code? Usually, a QGraphicsScene is used to add items that are derived from QGraphicsItem or QGraphicsObject. These items contain a paint function, which the system passes the QPainter to your item for rendering. If you just create a QPainter on its own and call draw functions, you're not going to see anything.

Comment: Could you draw the grid on the graphics view using the [`QGraphicsView::drawBackground`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#drawBackground) method? That is what I used in my project and the grid line thickness remains the same when zooming in and out, while the size of the grid changes.

Comment: Thanks this method helped me out and able to have a grid. :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Use cosmetic pen (with zero width)
2) By QT idiom graphics scene are independent from view (about your question of zoom in graphicsview), but you can extract zoom coefficients of view from passed QPainter object (QPainter *painter) - QPainter::worldTransform -> QTransform::m11 (horz_Scale) & QTransform::m22 (vert_Scale) - in this case you can recalculate grid anchors (for 100% zoom QTransform::m11 == QTransform::m22 == 1.) on 'fly'

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get you. Can you explain me with the help of example?

Comment: const qreal gridSize = 10. * qMax( painter->worldTransform().m11(), painter->worldTransform().m22() );//now 'gridSize' are depends from view zoom factor (10 px when zoom == 100%)